# Can anyone explain me the fisher score working

Tags: feature-selection, score

I have been working on feature selection and I wanted to know what does fisher score tell us about the data which helps us in feature selection.

Comment: If time permits, check this link, {https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20341/the-disadvantage-of-using-f-score-in-feature-selection}. The latter part goes into 'what' of f-score.

Answer (score 1):

From *Feature Selection for Classification: A Review (Jiliang Tang, Salem Alelyani and Huan Liu)*

> **Fisher Score:** Features with high quality should assign similar values to instances
>   in the same class and different values to instances from different
>   classes.

From *Generalized Fisher Score for Feature Selection (Quanquan Gu, Zhenhui Li, Jiawei Han)*

> **Fisher Score:** The key idea of Fisher score is to find a subset of features, 
>   such that in the data space spanned by the selected
>   features, the distances between data points in different classes are
>   as large as possible, while the distances between data points in the
>   same class are as small as possible.

If you are interested in the mathematical explanation, I would suggest the [second paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3725.pdf), on section 2 (A Brief Review of Fisher Score)